# Can't run XAMPP because of port?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, xampp

Sorry to bother guys. I have to develop a wordpress site for college, and i have to use xampp for it. but mysql and apache aren't working, i've researched and they say it could be a port error and i apparently need to turn off something called the World Wide Web Publishing Service. 
I originally had XAMPP working fine before i moved the folder into program files, but had to move it because wordpress wasn't working like that and the toturial had moved it into program files.

TLDR; is the World Wide Web Publishing Service important to keep your computer functioning or is turning it off no big deal?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn of Publishing Service - its IIS Service.

To be sure that is the service that held the port run netstat -ano and check if PID is "4" /commonly PID for system processes/. If the PID is different you can check the related process in task manager.